# Why does this neural network gives runtime warning?

Tags: python, numpy

This program causes an overflow in the nonlinear function. And finally, the output gets nan in all elements.

```
import numpy as np 

def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
Y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

w1 = np.random.random((2,2))
w2 = np.random.random((2,1))

for i in range(1000):
    a0 = X
    z1 = np.dot(a0,w1)
    a1 = nonlin(z1)

    z2 = np.dot(a1,w2)
    a2 = nonlin(z2)
    C = Y-a2
    #if(i%10==0):
    #   print(np.mean(np.abs(C)))

    Cdz2 = C*nonlin(z2,True)
    Cdz1 = Cdz2.dot(w2.T)*nonlin(z1,True)

    w2 += a1.T.dot(Cdz2)
    w1 += a0.T.dot(Cdz1)

print(a2)
```

The backpropagation method gives runtime warning in the nonlinear function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly how this works, but you can start debugging with `for i in range(45):` and then `print(x)` inside the function. Somewhere between iteration 45 and 50 it starts overflowing and at iteration 45 you will see that the values in `x` have begun to grow quite rapidly. In any case, this approach seems divergent not convergent.

Comment: Just, out of curiosity, why would you use x*(1-x) as your activation function, since it will in most cases output quite large negative values, which in turn cause overflow. Just changing boolean values to true in Cdz2 and Cdz1 calculations and basically switching to sigmoid activation function already seems to be converging.

Comment: @BogdanOsyka that's the sigmoid derivative for the backpropagation step

Comment: @filippo given f(x) = 1/(1+exp(-x)), the derivative of f(x) becomes f(x)*(1-f(x)). Which is not the same as x(1-x), while he is passing x to nonlin().

Comment: @BogdanOsyka see my answer, he confuses `x` and `f(x)`, that's the issue. He passes the wrong vectors as inputs to the sigmoid derivative.

Comment: @filippo sorry, did not pay attention to your answer. Completely agree with you, that was causing a problem

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of variable names can be a bit misleading: `z` is usually the output of the nonlinearity while you're using it for the linear combination and you're using `a` both for inputs and for outputs.

In the backpropagation step you need to compute the derivative of the output of the hidden and output layers, after the nonlinearity has been applied.

Which in your case should be

```
Cdz2 = C*nonlin(a2,True)
Cdz1 = Cdz2.dot(w2.T)*nonlin(a1,True)
```

where `z2` becomes `a2` and `z1` becomes `a1`

With this change it learns, I have:

```
[[ 0.23807658]
 [ 0.70736702]
 [ 0.70728018]
 [ 0.37925629]]
```

after `1000` steps and

```
[[ 0.01972628]
 [ 0.95332159]
 [ 0.95332158]
 [ 0.06245363]]
```

after `20000` steps.

I suggest you to use more sensible variable names, if you're following a textbook just use the same notation so it's easier to see how the formulas translate to code.